# Will update occur even if the join fails?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to debug some issues in an application and stumbled upon the following Query:

```
SET o.[IsProcessed] = 1,
    o.[Status] = f.[Flag],
    o.[IsProcessedTime] = GETDATE()
FROM [Customs].[dbo].[Out] o 
INNER JOIN [Storage].[dbo].[Facts] AS f
ON o.Msgd = f.MsgID
WHERE o.IsProcessed = 0
```

Question, will this Query still update the `Out` table with the `1` and `GETDATE()` values even if the join fails due to missing corresponding data in the table `f`?

Comment: You missed the `UPDATE o` in the beginning of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE only happens if using a SELECT here:

```
FROM       [Customs].[dbo].[Out] o 
INNER JOIN [Storage].[dbo].[Facts] AS f
ON         o.Msgd = f.MsgID
WHERE      o.IsProcessed = 0
```

It returns some row.

> ```
> create table foo(id int, data varchar(10));
> insert into foo values (1, ''),(2,''),(3,'');
>
> create table bar(id int, data varchar(10))
> insert into bar values (4,'aaa'),(5,'bbb');
>
> UPDATE     foo
> SET        data = bar.data
> FROM       foo f
> INNER JOIN bar
> ON         f.id = bar.id;
>
> SELECT     * 
> FROM       foo
> INNER JOIN bar
> ON         foo.id = bar.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | data | id | data
> -: | :--- | -: | :---
> ```
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO bar VALUES(1,'ZZZ'),(2,'YYY');
>
> UPDATE     foo
> SET        data = bar.data
> FROM       foo f
> INNER JOIN bar
> ON         f.id = bar.id;
>
> SELECT     * 
> FROM       foo
> INNER JOIN bar
> ON         foo.id = bar.id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | data | id | data
> -: | :--- | -: | :---
>  1 | ZZZ  |  1 | ZZZ 
>  2 | YYY  |  2 | YYY
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6e91f6610e04e5ce1dc78c9e9e8da723)*

Answer (score 2):

No, if nothing is found in the join, nothing will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

The update still technically happens, but since 0 rows are returned from the join, the table will not update directly from this query alone.

I can only see the table updating if there is a trigger on the table doing something strange.